# Random footer red line won't go away

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

I am working off a Word doc created by someone else, has text boxes.  I made edits, no problem but went to print and the red line shows up, I can move the red line up and down like it's a margin but it won't go away.

Comment: The image does not help at all. The document does not appear to be using a footer. If red line is in the right margin, I suspect you have Track Changes turned on and it is an unresolved change. If you want, save the document to a cloud location and provide a link to the document, not an image.